# How to set User/Group permission with Hadoop/Kerberos Setup?

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, cloudera

I am trying to setup Hadoop with Kerberos

I am following the CDH3 Security Guide.

Things went pretty well so far (HFDS works ok etc), but I am getting the following error when I try to submit the Job.

I run HDFS server as user HDFS and Hadoop as user called mapred. I Submit the job using user called bob, who is in mapred group.

Following are values I have for taskcontroller.cfg

```
mapred.local.dir=/opt/hadoop-work/local/
hadoop.log.dir=/opt/hadoop-1.0.3/logs
mapreduce.tasktracker.group=mapred
min.user.id=1000
```

Error I am getting is

```
java.io.IOException: Job initialization failed (24) with output: Reading task controller config from /etc/hadoop/taskcontroller.cfg
Can't get group information for mapred  - Success.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LinuxTaskController.initializeJob(LinuxTaskController.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$4.run(TaskTracker.java:1228)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.initializeJob(TaskTracker.java:1203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.localizeJob(TaskTracker.java:1118)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$5.run(TaskTracker.java:2430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:182)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LinuxTaskController.initializeJob(LinuxTaskController.java:185)
    ... 8 more
```

Error always comes with value given to "mapreduce.tasktracker.group=mapred" in the taskcontroller.cfg.

I have been debugging and looking in, and I think the problem is I have setup the permission among different users and groups wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated.